# Consider reopening question 113235

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

[Question 113235](https://askubuntu.com/q/113235/176889) is closed, being considered an exact duplicate of [question 43174](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43174/installing-ubuntu-on-external-hard-disk).

Now, I got the answer I needed before the question was closed, so I won't suffer much from it being closed, but I believe the questions aren't duplicates, and [question 113235](https://askubuntu.com/q/113235/176889) might have value for other people.

To me it's apparent by looking at how different the answers to the two questions are, that it isn't the same question, and that the answers to one question doesn't cover the second.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Link to the question under discussion - http://askubuntu.com/questions/113235/booting-ubuntu-located-on-hdd-from-usb

Comment: Any way can you quote your answer in pastebin?

Comment: Seems legit to me. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Hmmm. Fast reaction from our community, just took a year and 9 months after you made this meta post. Sorry for that.